# ChartJs Radar customisation in django

Tags: javascript, css, django, chart.js

I am trying to make charts work in my Django Application using chart.JS
But I am having some difficulties to make it look great !

here it how it looks: 
[image]

I would have two questions:

1) How can I add a bottom margin in the chart label 'Team Test"

2) How can I center verticaly the right chart

3) How can I increase the space of the chart and the  labels ?

Here is my code :

```
//graph 2//
    var info_process = new Chart(ctx2,{
      type: 'radar',
      data: {
        labels: labels_info,
        datasets: [{data: info_data,
                    label: team_name,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.9)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                  }]
            },
        options: {
           scale: {display: true,
                   ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true,
     }
                  },
           responsive:true,
           maintainAspectRatio: true,
          }
    });
    //end graph 2//

    //graph 3//
    var info_process = new Chart(ctx3,{
      type: 'radar',
      data: {
        labels: label_action,
        datasets: [{data: action_data,
                    label: team_name,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.9)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",

        }]
            },
        options: {
           scale: {display: true,
                   ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true,
     }
                  },
           responsive:true,
           maintainAspectRatio: true,
          }
    });
    //end graph 3//
```

Comment: what is your point number 2?

Comment: How can I center the chart on the right side ( triangle) vertically ?